# Find the missing record

Tags: sql, oracle

Three tables are connected to each other in the following manner:
Employee (ID, name) to Salary (ID, Employee_id, Vendor_id, total_amount, date_paid) by employee ID
Salary (ID, Employee_id, Vendor_id) to Vendor (Id, name) by vendor ID
Each employee ID has at least 2 vendors.
However one vendor is same for all employees – “ABC”
I need a list of employees that Vendor ABC was not paid.
For example:

```
Employee Vendor Month Total_amount
123     ABC     Jan 150
123     DEF     Jan 200
456     ABC     Jan 150
456     XYZ     Jan 250
123     DEF     Feb 200
456     ABC     Feb 150
456     XYZ     Feb 250
```

My result should be Employee_ID 123 for Feb, as Vendor ABC was not paid that month.

Comment: Ok. Rethinking this. I think you need a Month/Year table to show what Months they didn't pay any employee. And is the `Amount` that `ABC` pays the same for all employees? Too many unanswered variables.

Comment: They paid the employee every month thru the vendors. And yes, the amount is same always.

Comment: Ok. That's why you need a Month/Year table to see what month they miss paying an employee. Even if it's a temp table that you declare in your query.

Comment: So i create a Month/Year table that connects to the salary table by date_paid. but  my query results comes back with all the above records. where as i only need that one row (123 Feb) to be in the result as that is the only one that does not have a salary paid to ABC

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/260d9/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Employee, Vendor, Month, Total_amount ) AS
SELECT 123, 'ABC', 'Jan', 150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'DEF', 'Jan', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'ABC', 'Jan', 150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'XYZ', 'Jan', 250 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'DEF', 'Feb', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'ABC', 'Feb', 150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'XYZ', 'Feb', 250 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH EVA( Employee, Vendor, Total_Amount ) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         Employee,
         Vendor,
         Total_Amount
  FROM   table_name
),
Months ( Month ) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT MONTH FROM table_name
)
SELECT Employee, Vendor, Month, Total_Amount
FROM   EVA CROSS JOIN Months
MINUS
SELECT Employee, Vendor, Month, Total_Amount
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/260d9/2/0)**:

```
| EMPLOYEE | VENDOR | MONTH | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
|----------|--------|-------|--------------|
|      123 |    ABC |   Feb |          150 |
```